# In Coreos unit file, how do i write a json string to a file?

Tags: coreos

I want to write a json string to a file as part of my systemd unit file. I tried the below, but it fails:

```
[Unit]
Description=Write json to file
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c cat > /tmp/test.json <<- EOM
  {
    "Hello": "World",
    "Test": [{
      "foo": "bar"
    }]    
  }
  EOM
```

I don't want to escape quotes as my original json is little longer. Any better ideas?

Comment: What is the failure/messsage?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like '{' on line 5. I think it wants command in a single line and use '\' for line continuation